# NetworkStream write() with event name

Tags: c#, node.js, sockets

I have a simple TCP server written in C#, pinging out data at a specified interval and receiving the data I have a  NodeJS app.

I'm current sending the data from a `NetworkStream` like so:

```
private NetworkStream nwStream;
nwStream = clientMachine.GetStream();

nwStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); // Inside a loop
```

And receiving it in NodeJS like:

`client.on('data', (data) => {`

Is there any way to emit a different event, other than `data` from my C# TCP server? Using Socket.io I can `socket.emit('customEvent', someData)` and receive it like `socket.on('customEvent', receivedData)` but I'm unsure if I can achieve this in C#.

I'm not working with Socket.io, the above is just an example of the behaviour I'd like to achieve.

Comment: If you're talking to socket.io, you'll need to respect the socket.io protocol: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-protocol - presumably that tells you how to encode custom event names

Comment: I'm not talking to socket, that was just an example of behaviour that I'm aware of. I'm using a `NetworkStream` in C# and a `net.Socket()` in Node.

Comment: if you're using raw sockets at both ends, you'll just have to design your own protocol that embeds a name into each logical frame... TCP sockets themselves don't have any such mechanism, nor do raw packets

Comment: Ah thanks, my lack of knowledge is showing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using raw sockets at both ends, you'll just have to design your own protocol that embeds a name into each logical frame... TCP sockets themselves don't have any such mechanism, nor do raw packets.

A typical / simple way of doing this might be something like:

```
{Event name, UTF8}\r\n{length, 4 bytes little endian integer}{payload, length bytes}
```

If your event name might include newline/linefeed, then you'd need to use the payload length/payload approach for the event name, too.

Answer (score 1):

Socket.IO has it's own network protocol specified [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-protocol). The [encodeAsString(obj)](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-parser/blob/master/index.js#L150) function in 'socket.io-parser' may be what you're looking for.